# how to know a process on g++ compiled with -g

Tags: linux, debugging, compilation, g++, runtime

Is there a way to know at runtime that a process is compiled with the '-g' option?

I would like to operate differently in debug mode and release mode. Without using something like the -DDEBUG macro.

Comment: No, not effectively. The program may linked from a mix of some objects/translation units compiled with `-g` and others without, and the debugging info may be stripped out to a separate file or discarded at installation time.